# Does GHC reuse recursive function computations?

Tags: haskell, recursion, optimization

Let's say I have the following function

```
myFunction :: Integer->Integer->Integer->Rational
myFunction n m l
    | m>l  = 0
    | m==1 = 1 / n ** (l-1)
    | m==l = (p n l 1) * ( factorial (n-1) ) / factorial (n-l)
    | otherwise = (m/n) * (p n (l-1) m) + ((n-m+1)/n) p n (l-1) (m-1)
```

The details are not so important, the key point being that in order to evaluate the function for let's say n=100, l=200, and m=100 the code needs to solve the problem for (l=199,m=100) and (l=199,m=100), and so on. The problem is that in order to return anything one needs to reach l==m or m==1, my question is: Does GHC reuse the values it has already computed?

Other than solving the recursion (which is possible in this case) is there a way to improve the code so it does not recomputes values?

Comment: Haskell does not specify, GHC normally not, you can however define memorize patterns.

Comment: It's impractical to do this because GHC has no way of knowing how many different parameters you might call this with, so it might have millions or billions of calls it has to store so they can be reused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GHC does not attempt to automatically memoize the results of function calls, so two separate calls of `p 100 199 100` encountered in a recursion will usually require two separate evaluations.

If you want to memoize calls, there are two approaches.

You can use a memoization library.  There are quite a few available, so many that it's best to visit the [Hackage package list](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/) and search the page for "memoi" if you want to see what's available.  For example, with the [memoize](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize) package, your function could be memoized with something like the following:

```
import Data.Function.Memoize
import Data.Ratio

myFunction :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Rational
myFunction = memoFix3 f
  where f p n l m
          | m > l  = 0
          | m==1 = 1 % (n ^ (l-1))
          | m==l = (p n l 1) * ( factorial (n-1) % factorial (n-l) )
          | otherwise = (m % n) * (p n (l-1) m) + ((n-m+1) % n) * p n (l-1) (m-1)

        factorial n = product [1..n]

main = print $ myFunction 100 200 100
```

This generates an answer in a few seconds.  It also memoizes across calls, so additional `myFunction` calls in `main` would use memoized results from previous calls.

There is also a Haskell-specific technique where you build a data structure that represents the results of all possible (or at least all needed) function evaluations, leveraging laziness to automatically evaluate the required results, in dependency order and without duplicates, even if the data structure is conceptually infinite.

Here's a version of your function that uses a (finite) `Map` from all needed pairs `(l, m)` to the results:

```
import Data.Map.Lazy ((!))
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as Map
import Data.Ratio

myFunction :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Rational
myFunction n l m
  = p' ! (l, m)
  where p l m
          | m > l  = 0
          | m==1 = 1 % (n ^ (l-1))
          | m==l = (p' ! (l, 1)) * ( factorial (n-1) % factorial (n-l) )
          | otherwise = (m % n) * (p' ! (l-1, m)) + ((n-m+1) % n) * p' ! (l-1, m-1)
        p' = Map.fromList [ ((l',m'), p l' m')
                 | l' <- [1..l]
                 , m' <- [1..l'] ]

        factorial n = product [1..n]

main = do
  print $ myFunction 100 200 100
```

This one regenerates the map on each call, so the "memoization" isn't shared across calls.